# Error While Printing

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

My macro is shown below.  I am trying to save my excel sheet to a pdf document.  When I run my macro I get an "error while printing" message, followed by:
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

I am running Microsoft Excel for Mac version 15.13.1.

This is my Macro.  What is wrong?

```
Sub SAVE_DIRECTORY_IN_PDF_FORMAT()
Dim DIRECTORY As Worksheet
Dim DIRECTORY2 As Worksheet

Sheets("DIRECTORY").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="DIRECTORY.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("DIRECTORY2").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="DIRECTORY with Emails.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: The error occurs on the first occurrence of :  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _

Comment: Your code runs without error for me.

Comment: Could it be the version of Excel for Mac that I am using?

Comment: Does everything work when you manually save those tabs as pdfs?

Comment: Yes.  It works manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just came up against the same problem, which I agree seems to be a problem with Excel 2016 for Mac, and I think have a solution (albeit incredibly inelegant).

The problem seems to go away if you're overwriting an existing pdf file rather than creating a new one. So solution was to do a SaveAs on the workbook using the desired .pdf path, then do the ExportAsFixedFormat to the same path, then resave the workbook in its original path (if desired)...

```
Dim currentPath As String

currentPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="DIRECTORY.pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="DIRECTORY.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=currentPath
```

Comment: As a work around one can try this, till Microsoft issue.

Answer (score 0):

For the filename, try to include the path of the file, i.e. `Filename:="C:\Users\inm\Desktop\DIRECTORY.pdf"`.

Comment: I am using a Mac computer.  It doesn't have a C: drive.  My understanding is that the OS will place the file in the same directory as the application if not specifically defined.

Comment: I specified an exact path name for the file DIRECTORY.pdf with no change.  The error still occurs 1 line above the filename specification.

Comment: What does it look like when you use the macro recorder to save as PDF? That should help explain how to set the path, and/or see what might be going wrong.  "The error occurs one line above the filename specification" - you mean the part highlighted yellow is `Sheets("DIRECTORY").Select`? or `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat...`?

Comment: It doesn't record anything with the macro recorder.

Comment: Wait - if you go to the macro recorder, turn it on, then go to File --> Save as PDF, then save to the drive...it does *not* record anything in your workbook module?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that responded. I found the answer to the macro problem.
Excel 2016 for Mac does not support all the macro functions.  I had to go back to Excel 2011 for Mac for everything to work. Apparently there is no Excel 2013 for Mac.

I will now wait for Microsoft to upgrade the 2016 version to fix the macro issues.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with overwriting PDF still doesn't work with latest update 15.15 of MS Excel 2016 producing a message of "Error while printing" - 2011 works fine. Why they decided to change this VBA system - God only knows